# Can iOS Today Extension read URL Schemes from app's Info.plist

Tags: swift, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

We have our app target, and in that Info.plist, we defined URL Schemes that can be used to open the app with a URL.

Now we are adding a today extension.  We will want to have a table view who will open that URL from the extension.  We see how that is supported in the API.

Can we get the URL scheme from the app's Info.plist, or are we basically "hard coding" the value in the extension for it to call to open?

Answer (score 2):

To get infos.plist values you can use this:

```
let urlTypesArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleURLTypes")
```

You can find the right key (CFBundleURLTypes) opening the info.plist as Source Code (right click)

then, find the value :

```
let urlSchemesValue = urlTypesArray![0]["CFBundleURLSchemes"]
print("urlSchemesValue => \(urlSchemesValue)")
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @damien is not correct.  That will only return the **Extension** *Info.plist* file.

The correct answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189060/get-the-main-app-bundle-from-within-extension) in another SO post.