# Get main application NSBundle from extension

Tags: ios, bundle, ios-extensions, ios-app-group

Is it possible to get the container application `NSBundle` from the extension? 
As for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189060/get-the-main-app-bundle-from-within-extension?answertab=oldest#tab-top) answer, it is possible to get the container application bundle by "peeling" off two directory levels from the URL of the main bundle in the extension. As the respondent noticed, this method would break if the directory structure ever change. Is there a more robust way of doing it?

Comment: I'm aware that the question I marked this as a duplicate of (which is the one you linked to yourself), doesn't have an adequate answer for your case, however, the questions are rather identical, and an answer to your question, is necessarily a better answer to the former question. As such, the answers to this question will be found as an answer to the other question. Once a more adequate solution exists, it should be posted an answer to that question, and upvoted past the existing answers.